# Node.js Express disable automatic session creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express

If I enable the session feature of express via `app.use(express.session({secret: "12345"}));` the session cookie is set when the user first hits a page.

How can I disable this behavior and decide manually when to create a cookie, for example after a successful login? I am aware that I could just construct a cookie-header manually, but I would like to stay with express.session.

Comment: That will be so much tricky and error prone. Could you share with me why you want that?

Comment: Obviously there is not only a cookie created on the client side, but only resources allocated on the server side.. I thought it would be a good idea to avoid the later if the user never logs in, that is never needs the session. I mean it could be neglected if you dont expect a lot of visitors. I just dont like the idea of my memory or database storage getting "polluted". Is there something I am not seeing?

Comment: Large website will move static data to other domains, so most of requests will not create sessions, for example `static1.yourdomain.com/image/i1.jpg` will not create session. In `express`, you can move `app.use(express.static(...))` up to the top of other middlewares, so cookie and session middlewares will not run for static request.

Comment: I am already doing this, it greatly reduces the amout of sessions created that will never be used, but not to zero, so it cannot be called a solution. Can I specify an expiry date for a session entry in the sotrage (not on the client side)?

Answer (score 2):

Define the session support as middleware, but don't use `use`:

```
var sessions = express.session({
    // etc
});

...

app.get('/', function (req, resp) {
    // No session
});

app.post('/user', sessions, function (req, resp) {
    // Has sessions
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this option existed when this question was originally was posted but I was able to set the `saveUninitialized` option as `false` to do this.

https://github.com/expressjs/session#saveuninitialized

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a login method... I **SUPPOSE** you could do like that.

```
var sessionMW = express.session({secret:"12345"});

function login(req, res, next){
    //...
    if(success){
        return expressMW(req, res, next);
    }
}
```